# Elasticsearch 2.4.0 compatibilty with nutch 1.12

Tags: elasticsearch, ant, nutch

Can we use elasticsearch 2.4.0 with nutch 1.12. I used it directly and it threw error while indexing. Error is something like:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received message from unsupported version: [1.0.0] minimal compatible version is: [2.0.0].

Previously I was using elasticsearch 1.7. I have also used elastic-indexer2 plugin : https://github.com/ptorrestr/indexer-elastic2/  but the ant build failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The master branch of Nutch 1.x works with [ES 2.3.3](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/plugin/indexer-elastic/ivy.xml). It will be in the next release but for now you can download or clone it from https://github.com/apache/nutch.

There might be some minor changes to do to the ivy.xml and build.xml files, see [how to upgrade](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/plugin/indexer-elastic/howto_upgrade_es.txt) for details.